# RaspberryPi: Auto fix root-filesystem at boot-time

Tags: boot, linux, fsck

I have several RaspberryPi's running (~100). After a power breakdown some devices no longer started with the following error message:

[image]

It seems that the root-partition is broken. After I have connected the SD-card to the PC I was able to run `fsck` and within a few seconds everything was fixed and the SD-card booted without any problems.

My question: Is it possible to include `fsck` or something similar to the partition with the linux kernel? I like to make an automatic `fsck` at the boot-time to fix filesystem problems (especially problems onthe `/`-partition). Is this somehow possible or what is the best-practice to solve this problem?

The only alternative I see is to make the system read-only, but for this more effort is required. I hope I can avoid this now (and implement it later when I have more time).

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you considered a UPS?

Comment: This probably would be too expensive for all devices, but otherwise it could be a solution. Unfortunately some of the users also just disconnect the device from the power source and then the filesystem still could break.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After trying out the approach of creating a `forcefsck` file in `/`, fsck actually complained with the message:

> Please pass 'fsck.mode=force' on the kernel command line rather than creating /forcefsck on the root file system.

So instead of creating this file on every boot, I added `fsck.mode=force` to `/boot/cmdline.txt`.

This forces a fsck check on every reboot as well.

The setting `fsck.repair=yes` which is already in place should ensure that fsck always tries to repair issues, avoiding the need for manual interaction during the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can place a file named `forcefsck` in `/boot`. So you can plug the SD card into any computer that is able to mount the FAT file system and create the file there.

But I don't know in wich stage of booting your panic happens and if you will reach the fsck stage before it. So it might or might not work.

**EDIT:**

A quick search on the raspberry pi forum suggests that `forcesck` has to placed be on the root and not the boot partition. `/forcefsck` instead of `/boot/forcefsck`. I think the latter will run fsck only on the boot partition.

Comment: The "mount error" is shown at the very beginning. So I'm not sure if the "/forcefsck" trick will work, because I think the kernel would require to mount to filesystem to recognize this file? Unfortunately I cannot test this, because if I create the file, I first have to fix the filesystem.

Comment: Can you confirm that using the `/forcefsck` method it will automatically fix issues and not halt the process waiting for user input or anything like that?